# Merge a dataframe and column of others based on indexes

Tags: pandas, dataframe

Merge one dataframe and columns of 10 other dataframes based on index value.
I have a 10 dataframe with index column being the key identifier and last column being a Unique number for that dataframe.
I want to merge the first data frame with that last column of 9 other dataframes based on the index value.If new index arises in 9 other dataframes,merge should ignore that.

Ex:
Dataframe1:

| Uniq | Attr1 | Attr2 | Rating1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | b | 9 |
| 2 | d | c | 7 |
| 3 | y | x | 4 |

Dataframe2:

| Uniq | Attr1 | Attr2 | Rating2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | b | 6 |
| 4 | x | r | 8 |
| 3 | y | x | 9 |
| 2 | d | c | 5 |

Merged frame should be:

| Uniq | Attr1 | Attr2 | Rating1 | Rating2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | b | 9 | 6 |
| 2 | d | c | 7 | 5 |
| 3 | y | x | 4 | 9 |

Comment: are in both dataframes the last col called "Rating1"? and in the result there should be 2 columns ("rating1" and "rating2") ? or is it a typo and the column in df2 is "rating2"?

Comment: No,Last column name changes as I wrote,its Rating 2 in second dataframe

Comment: the pandas tag wiki page has a link to a question called "Pandas Merging 101". I think you'll find your answer in there.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

```
df_merged = df1.merge(df2, how='inner')
```

Comment: But that will exclude the outer columns i.e Rating1,Rating 2

Comment: i tested it myself. when running this line of code, i get exactly the df you want to have in your question